# Can Trogdor [find] some time to burninate this tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find) tag has the following description:

> This tag has multiple meanings. Please DO NOT use this tag if you're just trying to find something.

Naturally, contrary to the tag description, many of these questions are about trying to find something. There's little commonality in exactly what they're trying to find, and questions range in topic from finding something on the DOM to finding files in Bash to finding and replacing text in SQL. There are some Excel/VBA questions thrown in for good measure.

This tag is highly ambiguous and does *not* mean the same thing in all common questions. There is very little that ties these questions together, and it's hard to imagine how someone could be an expert in all of the topics that it matches, and it would be of little use in finding questions to answer.

There are a few high-rep users that have answered 50+ questions in this tag, but they appear to be experts primarily in Linux, Unix, and Bash, so they likely answered questions with this tag merely by coincidence.

Many of the topics that this identifies aren't even on-topic as they're primarily about Linux andUnix commands, not programming.

Can we burninate this?

Comment: Can you link to the meta post with that Trogdor character? (Shog9's?)